# Auto-Resolution of Constructor parameters from Unity Container

Tags: c#, unity-container

I would like to create an app where it would auto-magically resolve all my constructor parameters using a unity container. Does anyone have an example on how to accomplish this?

I saw this being done when using Owin but I'm not sure how to whip up something similar for use in any application that I build. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* constructor parameters as in "all constructors that are ever called" is a heavy requirement. Assuming a desktop application: you can get close if you go for Prism with Unity and use the `ViewModelLocator` to create your view models.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: What about this one? https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/8-ViewModelLocator It's rather simple, sure, but it shows the concept. Actually, there's just one single _new_ in there...